# SQL Visual studio checking if access table exists

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I am trying to develop a code that will search an access file for a table name and return something that I can use to tell me whether or not one needs to be made, below is my code for creating a table.

```
                    string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" 
                    + PATHTEXTBOX.Text;
                    OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(connString);
                    connect.Open();
                    string query1 = "CREATE TABLE " + jobnumbers[i3] + " (JobTime CHAR, 
                    Name CHAR)";
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query1, connect);
                    command.Connection = connect;
                    command.CommandText = query1;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connect.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the following works for you, pass a table name, alter the connection string. Returns true if table name exists, false otherwise.

```
public class Utilities
{

    public static bool TableExists(string tableName)
    {
        using (var cn = new OleDbConnection() { ConnectionString = "Your connection string" })
        {
            var schema = cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
                OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

            return schema.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Any(row => 
                string.Equals(row.ItemArray[2].ToString(), tableName, 
                    StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        }
    }
}
```